# Views are not being loaded

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

I'm creating a .net core app.
For keepings things clean I'm trying to split up all the different "services"

In my master `startup.cs` I run the following:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });

    ProjectA.Startup.ConfigureServices(services);
    ProjectB.Startup.ConfigureServices(services);
    ProjectC.Startup.ConfigureServices(services);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ProjectA.Startup.Configure(app, env);
    ProjectB.Startup.Configure(app, env);
    ProjectC.Startup.Configure(app, env);
}
```

And this seem to work great, all my API endpoints are available.

Now I'm trying to add some razor pages in ProjectC, but then I get the following error when going to the `/home` page:
[image: Error problem]

This is the `startup.cs` of that project:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
       
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
            .RequireAuthorization();
        });

    }
}
```

The folder structure is made as following:

```
.
├── src/
│   ├── ProjectA/
│   │   ├── Controllers/
│   │   └── startup.cs
│   ├── ProjectB/
│   │   ├── Controllers/
│   │   └── startup.cs
│   ├── ProjectC/
│   │   ├── Controllers/
│   │   │   └── HomeController.cs
│   │   ├── Views/
│   │   │   ├── Home/
│   │   │   │   └── index.cshtml
│   │   │   ├── Shared/
│   │   │   │   ├── _Layout.cshtml
│   │   │   │   ├── _Nav.cshtml
│   │   │   │   └── ...
│   │   │   ├── _ViewImports.cshtml
│   │   │   └── _ViewStart.cshtml
│   │   └── startup.cs
│   └── MainProject/
│       └── startup.cs
└── project.sln
```

Any idea/suggestion on how to get it working? I tried some static file configurations, but none gave me any result

Comment: Can you show your folder structure for your views, and the controller action you are using to get the view please.

Comment: @NolanBradshaw added the requested info

Comment: Try to add the absolute path when returning the view and see if it pulls it properly. (Ex. "~/Views/Index.cshtml") This is often my first step when resolving this types of issues.

Comment: @NolanBradshaw That gives me The view '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' was not found

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

there are 2 things that needed to be done:

1. Add a `razor class library` not a normal `class library`
2. in the csproj add following;

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  <Content Update="Views\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```